# Mock Dictionary in R

Tags: r, dictionary, dataframe

I'm trying to write a function that essentially acts like a dictionary in R. The mapping I'd like is:

'one' -> '1', 'two' -> '2', 'three' -> '3', 'four' -> '4'

and the function combines the results in a string (I can do this using `paste()`).

So, when the function is given the input `x <- c('one, 'two', 'four')`, the output would be `"1, 2, 4"`.

I've tried using a data frame like this:

```
keys <- c('one', 'two', 'three', 'four')
values <- ('1', '2', '3', '4')
dict <- data.frame(keys, values)
```

But I can't seem to call specific values of `keys` to get the corresponding values. Also, this doesn't seem like a very efficient way to do this. What's the best way to get this done in R? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you call "keys" you could treat as the names of the corresponding values:

```
nums <- c('1','2','3','4')
names(nums) <- c('one','two','three','four')
f <- function(v)paste(nums[v],collapse = ', ')
```

For example,

```
> f(c('one', 'three', 'four', 'three'))
[1] "1, 3, 4, 3"
```

The lack of a built-in dictionary/hash table in R is a drawback of the language. [Here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/hash-table-performance-in-r-part-i/) is an interesting discussion of various workarounds. Depending on your needs, you might want to experiment with package [hash](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/hash/hash.pdf).

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize there was such a thing as ``names(nums)``. Thank you!

Comment: @Max If this answers your question, please accept it as an answer. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

I believe `list` is the most closest form of dictionary available in R. For example:

```
# create a list
nums <- list('1','2','3','4') # value 
names(nums) <- c('a','b','c','d') # keys

# function which extract values
func <- function(f)
{
    return(nums[[f]])
}

# extract value 
print(func('a'))
[1] "1"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [dict](https://github.com/mkuhn/dict) package in R which isn't on CRAN but can be installed via github. Refer to readme for installation instructions. Untested solution, but I think it should work!

```
library(dict)

# Initialize 
d <- dict() 
l <- list(1,2,3,4)
l1 <- list("one","two","three","four") 

# Loop to create a dictionary     
for(i in 1:length(l)) {
   for(j in 1:length(l1) {

       d[[ l[i] ]] <-  l1[j]

   }
}


# Function to return the value when passed corresponding key
func <- function(k) {

    return(d$get[k])

}

# Func call
func(1)
```